# Converting date from 20160729161455 to 29/07/2016 16:14:55

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

How can i convert `20160729161455` to `29/07/2016 16:14:55`?

I've tried the following but it did not work:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String dateID = 20160729161455;

try
{
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateID);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException ex){}
```

Comment: Point is: your **parsing** format has to match your input. No space in your input, thus using a parser that excepts a space cant work in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do. You need 2 SimpeDateFormat objects:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateParser= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String dateID = "20160729161455";

try
{
    Date date = dateParser.parse(dateID);
    System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));
} catch (ParseException ex){
    ex.printStacktrace();
}
```

In first step you have to parse the value and in second you have to format it in the new format.